# I try to inject React.createContext Api into Thunk withExtraArgument but don't understand something

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, inject, react-context

I'm new to React learning and now I have this Redux Thunk that I need to inject this `firebase` Context into.

The `FirebaseContext` Context:
(It also create an `withFirebase` that I use with Rect.Componets.)

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);
    
    export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
        <FirebaseContext.Consumer>{firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}</FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    );

export default FirebaseContext;
```

This is how the FirebaseContext.Provider is assigned:

```
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase';
import store from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,

    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

And creating the Redux store I inject it like this standars procedure:

```
thunk.withExtraArgument(FirebaseContext),
```

And here is my Redux Thunk and when running this the Thunk is called but the `FirebaseContext` must be the `value={new Firebase()}`  `value`but don't understand how to do that I have search for hours and also tried using the `withFirebase` to wrap the Thunk with but Thunk did not like that!

```
function doSomeWork() {
    return (dispatch, FirebaseContext) => {
        function work() {
            const firebase = FirebaseContext; // HERE IS THE PROBLEM 
            const userRef = firebase.userDoc(firebase.auth.currentUser.uid);
            dispatch(doSomeWorkStart());
            .....
        }
        return work;
    };
}
```

How can I pass the "value" that is the `new Firebase()` into my Thunk??

Comment: Have you considered using the useContext hook in your component instead to access the firebase context?

Comment: Yes I have tried the `useContext` but this Thunk is called from an React.Component so that did not work. Hook's dont like React.Components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

### Option 1:

I think instead of trying to pass the FirebaseContext down to your thunk, you should instead just pass the Firebase object itself. You can't use context inside of thunk, so either you will need to pass the context value as an argument to your thunk from the component, or simply provide it when you configure the store.

```js
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './firebase';
import reducer from './redux/reducer';

const firebase = new Firebase();
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(firebase)),
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={firebase}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Also, you still need to correct the order of arguments in your thunk. Redux-thunk will call your function with `dispatch, getState, firebase` in that order. Even though you aren't using `getState` you can't ignore it. It will still be pass as an argument to your thunk.

```js
function doSomeWork() {
  return (dispatch, getState, firebase) => {
    function work() {
      const userRef = firebase.userDoc(firebase.auth.currentUser.uid);
      dispatch(doSomeWorkStart());
    }
    return work;
  };
}
```

### Option 2:

The alternative option, as mentioned, is to access the context inside of your component, and pass it as an argument to your action creator.

```js
function doSomeWork(firebase) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    function work() {
      const userRef = firebase.userDoc(firebase.auth.currentUser.uid);
      dispatch(doSomeWorkStart());
    }
    return work;
  };
}
```

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const firebase = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(doSomwWork(firebase))
  },[])

  return <></>;
}
```

However, I think the first option is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin yea I know but I run this code without `getState` argument and `dispatch` and `FirebaseContext` are ok, I don't need `getState`

Comment: You see in code sample the `// HERE IS THE PROBLEM`, how do I get the `Firebase`from the `FirebaseContext `

Comment: @Kid I've updated my answer to include two examples of how to pass your firebase argument into redux-thunk.

Comment: Thanks @Bejamin I learn so much from you. The Option 1: worked perfect